# Deriving bounds on a parameter for the following determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I would like to derive the least restrictive bounds on the parameter $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ to satisfy the following expression:

$$ \det \big(I + A(\gamma)\big) \leq 1, $$

where

$$A (\mu) = (e e^T) \big( x x^T - (x^T x) \cdot I \big) + \gamma \cdot (x x^T) \big( e e^T - (e^T e) \cdot I \big)$$

with $I$ being the identity matrix of appropriate size, $(x,e) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ are **each** column vectors; thus, there are rank one matrices outside of the above expression and scalars sitting with $I$ inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\mu  = \gamma$ in the second equation of the problem statement, the limits on $\gamma$ depend on the value of
$$\sigma  = {\left| {\underline {\bf{e}} } \right|^2}{\left| {\underline {\bf{x}} } \right|^2} - {\left( {{{\underline {\bf{e}} }^T}\underline {\bf{x}} } \right)^2} - 1$$

If $\sigma  > 0$, then $\gamma  \ge \frac{1}{\sigma }$.

If $\sigma  < 0$, then $\gamma  \le \frac{1}{\sigma }$.

If $\sigma  = 0$, then the value of the determinant is zero independent of the value of $\gamma$.

See [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-QW2SfiqX-UoJrB1sbumuYFu1k9b4Twe) for a detailed derivation.  I have verified this result numerically.

Comment: Hi -- thank you so much for this! I just had a couple of clarification Q's on the derivation (some steps I could not follow): in equation (6) --> why does the first term not have a det in front?  also, why does $B^{-1} (\gamma)$ appear after $e^T_n$? also, I was not able to follow the results in eqns (7) and (8). If you may have some time to write these out, then, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Equations (6) and (7) use the "matrix determinant lemma" in its dyadic form (where the adjustment to the full matrix is an outer product of vectors).  There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) describing this well known transformation of the determinant.  The Woodbury identity is similar, but applies to the matrix inverse rather than the determinant.  It also has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) describing it. Look at these - should be easy to see how I have used them.

Comment: PS - in the paper I label it the "generalized Woodbury identity", but its actually just the standard identity, which again applies to outer products of rank one vectors rather than higher rank outer products.